# How should I structure my settings table with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, organization

What's the best way to structure a MySQL table for storing admin settings?

Like this?

```
Setting _|_ Value
setting1 |   a
setting2 |   b
setting3 |   c
setting4 |   d
setting5 |   e
```

Or like this?

```
|--------|_setting1_|_setting2_|_setting3_|_setting4_|_setting5_|
Settings |    a     |    b     |    c     |    d     |    e     |
```

Or maybe some other way?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Table name = 'settings'

```
name  | varchar <-- primary key
value | varchar
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name = 'default_printer';
```

This option is nice and easy and it will work well with 10, or 10,000 settings. With the other option you'll have to add a new column, which would be a completely pointless waste of time.

Edit

After your 1st comment you could choose multiple values like this:

```
SELECT * FROM settings WHERE name IN ('default_printer','default_page_size');
```

:-)

Comment: +1 for explicitly pointing out that I needed a primary key, since I forgot it in my original post ;) ... Looks pretty good. I especially like that, using this setup, I could make a function that would allow me to select a setting (or multiple settings at a time), which would be very handy.

Comment: I concur, I've added another possible SQL statement, we use this method on our ERP system, holds lots of settings. :-)

Comment: What if you want to store different types in "Value", is it acceptable to later make the cast in your code to the type you expect? If you have very few settings and they are all different types i.e. string, int, float, would it make more sense to use the second schema?

Comment: @radtek you could have a column type (if you want to store it with the value), and then one column for each type you want to have. The problem with this approach is that you will have lots of nulls although you win in flexibility.

Comment: how to update values in this table could you please share the query

Comment: this looks like EAV, an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the first option (`Setting`, `Value`) as columns. But also consider adding additional, meta columns as well, such as `Description` (would come in handy if you have alot of ambiguous settings), `PreviousValue`, `LastUpdated`, `UpdatedBy`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example, name-value pairs or EAV, allows for a good deal more flexibility.

Check out the [wiki page about EAV modelling in databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this has always been my challenge. Each has its own advantages and disadvantages, although I have sometimes used both examples in projects and it depends on where it is used.

The first is more for when the user is going to save certain settings of the site under the key in the database and it is dynamic, meaning that something may be added at any time. Even you as a developer want to add something new every moment. Because by adding a record as a new key, you do not need to rebuild the structure of the database and models, and it saves time. In this structure you can not specify a specific type for each data.
Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ab8aa/1/1

But in the second, adding a new key depends on changing the structure of the database and changing the models. So more for when you have fixed and specific keys that are not going to change every time. However, if, for example, the settings are to be categorized for a specific language or a specific user group, this method still makes the task much easier because each record can be for a specific user or a specific language. In such cases, querying on this structure is easier than the previous method. In this structure, you can set and validate data by string, number, date, etc.
Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b99d52/1/1

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it depends. Solution 1 is simpler. Sol #2 easily integrates with ORMs, but may hit DB row size limitations.
Google for OTLT (as in One True Lookup Table problem)
How much settings do you have(few? dozens? hundreds?) How often will you need them?

Comment: Dozens. I may need some of them as often as every pageview. That is, an admin setting may affect the view of certain pages every time they are displayed. As an example, one of the settings would be the name of a featured product, and another setting would be the filename for the gif image of said product.